# Inserting all 0's or all 1's into database

Tags: php

I have the following code, which almost works:

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
        $fields = array(
            'col1'  => 'cb1', 
            'col2'  => 'cb2', 
            'col3'  => 'cb3', 
            'col4'  => 'cb4', 
            'col5'  => 'cb5',
            'col6'  => 'cb6', 
            'col7'  => 'cb7', 
            'col8'  => 'cb8', 
            'col9'  => 'cb9', 
            'col10' => 'cb10'
        );

        $parts = array();

        foreach( $fields as $dbfield => $field ) {
            $parts[] = '`' . $dbfield . '` = :' . $dbfield;
        }

        $dbh = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'user', 'pass' );
        $dbh -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

        $sth = $dbh -> prepare( 'UPDATE `table1` SET ' . join( ', ', $parts ) . ' WHERE `id` = :id' );

        // temp simulation value
        $id = 1;

        $sth -> bindParam( ':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT, 4 );

        foreach( $fields as $dbfield => $field ) {

            $value = isset( $_POST[$field] ) ? 1 : 0;
            $sth -> bindParam( ':' . $dbfield, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT, 4 );

        }

        $sth -> execute();

        $dbh = null;
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post">

            <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" /><br />

            <input type="checkbox" name="cb2" /><br />

            <input type="checkbox" name="cb3" /><br />

            <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" /><br />

            <input type="checkbox" name="cb5" /><br />

            <input type="checkbox" name="cb6" /><br />

            <input type="checkbox" name="cb7" /><br />

            <input type="checkbox" name="cb8" /><br />

            <input type="checkbox" name="cb9" /><br />

            <input type="checkbox" name="cb10" />

            <input type="submit" value="save" />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

It should be inserting 0's or 1's depending on the checkbox selected, but for some reason it inserts 0's into all columns no matter which checkboxes are selected.  However, if the last checkbox is selected, it inserts a 1 into all columns.

Comment: Blimey; someone actually using PDO!

Comment: "it inserts 0's into all columns no matter which checkboxes are selected. However, if the last checkbox is selected, it inserts a 1 into all columns." This is a complete contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bindParam` binds the actual variable `$value` (by reference) which, by the time the loop ends, has a value based on `$_POST['cb10']`. (Recall that PHP has no block scope, so there is only one `$value` variable, as opposed to one for each loop iteration.)

I think you meant to use `bindValue`.

Take a peek at [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php):

> bool PDOStatement::bindParam ( mixed $parameter , mixed &$variable [,
>   int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR [, int $length [, mixed
>   $driver_options ]]] )
>
> bool PDOStatement::bindValue ( mixed $parameter
>   , mixed $value [, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR ] )

Comment: I have tried to change bindParam to bindValue and remove the length, but it gives errors.

Comment: @oshirowanen: Are you going to share?

Comment: I'll have to come back to this tomorrow when I get back to my dev machine. Hope to post the error message then.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This Change should do the trick

```
 foreach( $fields as $dbfield => $field ) {
        $parts[] = '`' . $dbfield. '` = :' . $_POST[$field];
    }
```

Comment: No; he's using `$dbfield` as the bind parameter name.

Comment: I just tried that and it is giving me `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /var/www/page1.php on line 48 Call Stack: 0.0009 342176 1. {main}() /var/www/page1.php:0 0.0024 351640 2. PDOStatement->execute() /var/www/page1.php:48`

Comment: You don't appear to understand prepared statements, @Dukeat. Please read the PDO documentation.